# Hex character in BEGIN block

Tags: awk, printf, hex, posix

I can print a hex character in the process block

```
$ awk '{printf "%c", $0}' <<< 0x21
!
```

However the same character will not print in the BEGIN block

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%c", 0x21}'
0
```

How can I print a hex character in the BEGIN block?

Comment: The same command(BEGIN block) is printing '!' for me in GNU Awk 3.1.5

Comment: Could you use `awk 'BEGIN {printf "%c", '$((0x21))'}'`?

Comment: @A.M.D Try this `awk -c 'BEGIN {printf "%c", 0x21}'` to run `awk` in `traditional` mode and you see that it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading a string awk will recognize hex numbers.

When reading a number awk will not recognize hex numbers, it will toss out
everything starting with the first non number.

So with the first example `$0` is a string and all is well. With the second
example `x21` is tossed out and `0` is left. A workaround is to pass `0x21` as a
string

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%c", +"0x21"}'
!
```

Comment: It doesn't support hex, "0x21"+0 is converted to 33 which is then passed to the printf

Comment: The `--posix` did the trick.  You can write it like this  `+"0x21"` too.

Comment: Also you are passing as a number not string.

Answer (score 3):

GNU `awk` supports hex notation but [traditional `awk` does not](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-28).  The POSIX standard for `awk` is [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) and it states:

> An integer constant cannot begin with 0x or include the hexadecimal
>   digits 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', or 'F'.

Here is one method that uses `bash` to supply the constant string that you want to a POSIX awk:

```
awk -v p=$'\x21' 'BEGIN {printf "%c", p}'
```

#### References

- `-v p=string`

  The `-v` option allows `awk` variables to be defined via the command line.  This is documented in the POSIX spec under "options" [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html).
- `$'\x21'`

  The `$'...'` construct allows many special characters to be added to `bash` strings.  Here, we add a hexadecimal.  This is documented in the `bash` manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

Comment: awk does support hex notation with strings, see my answer

Comment: @StevenPenny I see your very interesting answer and it works for me under `GNU --posix`.  Did it work for you under any other version of `awk`?  I just scanned the POSIX spec and found no indication that hex support is part of POSIX awk.

Comment: @John1024 It appears that hex numbers can be used as numbers but are not interpreted as strings. As in stevens answer converting the hex to a number using `+0` allows the `printf` to read it as `33`. In GNU versions of awk it differentiates between strings and numbers better so it will convert the hex to a number automatically in the right context.